# Chrome: Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging. ReactJs and jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, google-chrome

> I am just changing the url when page go to particular height. but
>   it shows me error in the 
>   chrome :**Throttling history state changes to
>   prevent the browser from hanging.** after 1200 height. but it is working
>   fine in the firefox so some one know how to prevent from this warning
>   if yes please tell me  ?

```
 function myFunction(){
            var h = ($("html").scrollTop());
                        if(h == 0){
                             window.history.pushState(null,null,'/');
                            // console.log("0oo");
                        }
                        else if(h >= 1 && h <= 600){
                             window.history.pushState(null,null,"abc");
                            // console.log("test");
                        }
                        else if (h >= 600 && h <= 1200) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, 'def');
                            // console.log("test1");
                        }
                        else if (h >= 1200 && h <= 1800) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, 'ghi');
                            // console.log("test2");
                        }
                        else if (h >= 1800 && h <= 2400) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, 'jkl');
                            // console.log("test3");
                        }
                        else if (h >= 2400 && h <= 3000) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, 'mno');
                            // console.log("test4");
                        }
                        else if (h >= 3000 && h <= 3600) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, 'pqr');
                            // console.log("test5");
                        }
                        else if (h >= 3600 && h <= 4200) {
                            history.pushState(null, null, 'stu');
                            // console.log("test6");
                        }
                        else{

                        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue - I got around it by checking the current pathname to see if it *needs* to be changed before changing it. This hugely cuts down the number of history state changes, and therefore avoids this warning.

Applying this idea to your code, I would do this:

```
if(h == 0){
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
        window.history.pushState(null,null,'/');
    }
}
else if(h >= 1 && h <= 600){
    if (window.location.pathname !== "abc") {
        window.history.pushState(null,null,"abc");
    }
}
... etc
else if (h >= 3600 && h <= 4200) {
    if (window.location.pathname !== "stu") {
        window.history.pushState(null,null,"stu");
    }
}
```